# Azure Web App Support for .NET Framework 4.8.1 | Getting build error in cloud, because target is v4.8.1

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, .net-framework-version

The .NET Framework version 4.8.1 was released in August of this year.  When will it be supported in Azure Web Apps?

I upgraded a solution with multiple projects targeting v4.8.1.  Building on my local machine is fine - no errors; however, when I attempted a build via a pipeline in ADO, I get the error:

`##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1217,5): Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks`

Perhaps it's a setting I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET Framework 4.8.1 is already installed in Microsoft-hosted agent `windows-latest` OR `windows-2022`. It is documented [here](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md#net-framework).

So, if you are using Microsoft-hosted agent `windows-2019`, please try to use `windows-latest` OR `windows-2022` instead.

Besides, another solution is to use [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops). This will set your local machine as an agent, so that all the software you are using in the pipeline come from your local machine.

**Update:**

Please try to add a [NuGet Tool Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops) at the beginning of your pipeline. Here is an exmaple:

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.8.0'
```

This task can find, download, and cache a specified version of NuGet and add it to the PATH.

Comment: I updated the OS to windows-latest, as suggested.  Now, I get dozens of errors like the following complaining that certain packages are not compatible?


 `Package Azure.Identity 1.1.1 is not compatible with net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1). Package Azure.Identity 1.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)`

Comment: Some further investigation of the above error, is that NuGet for windows-latest & windows-2022 is using 'Detected NuGet version 4.1.0.2450 / 4.1.0'  which is not new.  I checked a pipeline using windows-2019 and it is using NuGet 5.8.0.  Seems like this is the issue.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello @T H, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I was searching - with little luck - to find out how to specify the version of NuGet.  Odd that it would default to an old version.